# HTML5 как оформить статью с комментариями используя семантические теги

Tags: html, html5, теги, семантика

У меня на сайте есть статья к которой можно писать комментарии.
Как мне оформить статью и комментарии с помощью семантических тегов html5.

Вот думаю над такими вариантами:

```
<main>
    Сама статья
</main>
<article>
    комментарий 1
</article>
<article>
    комментарий 2
</article>
```

или

```
<article>
    Сама статья
</article>
<article>
    комментарий 1
</article>
<article>
    комментарий 2
</article>
```

или

```
<article>
    Сама статья
</article>
<section>
    комментарий 1
</section>
<section>
    комментарий 2
</section>
```

или

```
<main>
    Текст статьи
    <article>
        комментарий 1
    </article>
    <article>
        комментарий 2
    </article>
</main>
```

Answer (score 1):

По большому счету, в вашем случае однозначного ответа дать не получится.
Тэги `section` и `main` это, по сути, одно и то же - `<main>` это равноценно `<section class="main">` с логической точки зрения, но семантически контент статьи будет главным на странице по отношению к комментариям, например, потому `<main>` использовать правильнее.

Если комментарии будут развёрнутыми, то можно их разместить в `<article>`, тогда вариант ниже наиболее подходит:

```
<main>
    Текст статьи
    <article>
        комментарий 1
    </article>
    <article>
        комментарий 2
    </article>
</main>
```

Если комментарии не будут нести глубокого смысла и представлять ценности для поисковика, то можно их обернуть просто в `<div>`, а саму статью выделить в `<article>`:

```
<main>
    <article>
        Текст статьи
    </article>
    <div>
        комментарий 1
    </div>
    <div>
        комментарий 2
    </div>
</main>
```

Если же блоки с контентом статьи и с комментариями будут реализованы и подключены независимо друг от друга, то можно сделать, например, так:

```
<main>
    <article>
        Текст статьи
    </article>
</main>
<section class="comments">
    <div>
        комментарий 1
    </div>
    <div>
        комментарий 2
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Так что я знаю будут ли комментарии нести смысл? Это от пользователей зависит, какие комментарии они напишут. Но пока думаю для комментариев использовать `article` так как он дружит с `<time pubdate>дата</time>`

Comment: div это не семантический тег, он относится к визуальной разметке, думаю он тут не поможет, использование `<section class="comments">` тоже к семантике не относится, это визуальная разметка

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин если ввели семантические теги, то это не означает, что их надо пихать вдоль и поперёк. использование `div` никто не отменял и вряд ли когда-нибудь отменит

Comment: да, я имел ввиду, что для поисковиков `div` на уровне структуры не разграничивает где заканчивается один комментарий и начинается другой. В одном комментарии может быть несколько `div`-ов. А вот указав `article` или `section` разграничение сразу определяется.

Answer (score 0):

На данный момент выбрал такое решение

```
<main>
    <article> текст статьи <article>

    <article> комментарий1 <article>
    <article> комментарий2  <article>
    <article> комментарий3  <article>
    <article> комментарий4  <article>
</main>
```

потому что и комментарии и сама статья это независимые самодостаточные эллементы, то есть соответсвуют тегу `<article>` .
Единственное что мне не нравится то что и статья и ответы с семантической точки зрения получаются идентичными, хотя на самом деле статья более важная чем комментарии.
Для решения этой ситуации думаю сделать две секции со статьёй и с комментариями.

```
<main>
    <section>        
        <article> текст статьи <article>
    </section>
    <section>    
        <article> комментарий1 <article>
        <article> комментарий2  <article>
        <article> комментарий3  <article>
        <article> комментарий4  <article>
    </section>
</main>
```

так будет показано что статья отделена от комментариев